# How to group different data with same information from column with Database Access using PHP And Show In Table

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc

sorry about this dummy question... but i have a concern how to get this solution, for example:
i have one table like this in my db

```
    -------------------------------
    ID      POperator      Line
    1          Jhon         A
    2          David        B
    3          Jacob        A
    -------------------------------

I want to get the information like this but in a table in web environment 
-------------------------------
LINE A DATA
first table
ID POperator         Line
1     Jhon            A
3     Jacob           A

Second Table
ID POperator     Line
2   David         B
------------------------------------
```

This is my code trying get the records from database

```
$db = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=".$db."",$user,$password);

$result = odbc_exec($db,"select PTime,PSample,PRemarks,PLine,POperator from POV WHERE PDate= #".$current_date."# ORDER BY PLine ASC");
```

if somebody knows how to change the logic to get the data or how to type the instructions in PHP to obtain the data grouped in tables i will appreciate a lot.

I using ODBC to get connection with Microsoft Access as Database.

Comment: Your query shows fields not in the sample data. Sorting records by date or other criteria is simple. If you want two tables then I expect you have run two queries with filter criteria and set up two tables. What exactly is your issue - how to use filter in query or how to build tables in web environment?

Comment: I was triying using the sentence GROUP BY PLine to get the information according the PLine data but wasn't work for show the tables according the logic that I want, by chance you know how could be better? Get first lines A and B using sentence GROUP BY and then a second query for each line and then put this data in multiple tables according wich Line is?

Comment: GROUP BY is for aggregation of data, not ordering. Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Your question shows two output datasets - that means two queries.

Comment: Make sure your records are sorted by Line - and then simply compare the value of the current record with that of the previous one, while you are looping over your data. Depending on whether they are the same or different, you need to output just the current record's data, or some additional stuff for your table headers first.

Comment: After everything, i did found the solution and i want to shared what i did, sorry if nobody tried to understood my question at the end of everything the solution was an multidimensional array.